# Why am I not getting the soap header?

Tags: wcf

Why is this so hard in WCF 4.0

I add a custom header in my client

Authorization: 18732818 gfdsgShoyh3sfayql6jWCRc=

so that my header looks like the following

> GET http://HOSTNAME/Public/Xml/SyncReply/TestClearUsername?Id=1 HTTP/1.1
>
> Authorization: 18732818 gfdsgShoyh3sfayql6jWCRc=
>
> Host: HOSTNAME
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive

in my wired up service responder I can access the property Id and get the value 1. I would also like to access the value Authorization, but it always shows as null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'd rather not need to bother wiring up behaviors in WCF?

Comment: This seems like quite an angry question, but it doesn't include many details which will help us understand what you're trying to do. We can't troubleshoot what you're trying to do unless you at least let us know *how* you're trying to do it

Comment: That would be a HTTP header - **NOT** a SOAP header.....  no wonder my answer didn't work for you. You should be more precise when formulating your questions instead of punishing those who try to help you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling I finally found the answer to this so I will post it here so it might be of use to someone else. I am assuming this is an undocumented feature, since it is so well hidden, but someone else might know different.

I found this enumeration `System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest.HeaderAuthorization` (value=24)

and this method `System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest.GetKnownRequestHeader(24)`

Just to summarize the reason Authorization was hiding from me was that its a reserved header value. if you add a random word and want to retrieve you can use.

```
.GetUnknownRequestHeader("YOUR_WORD_HERE").
```

so in full you need

```
HttpRequestContext hrc = (HttpRequestContext)this.RequestContext;

RequestAttributes ra = (RequestAttributes)hrc.RequestAttributes;

System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest hwr = ra.HttpWorkerRequest;

string Auth = hwr.GetKnownRequestHeader(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest.HeaderAuthorization);
```